# Orchard can't load media

Tags: orchardcms

I'm using Orchard 1.7.2. I created widget with MediaPickerField for video file. On the front-end i trying to get this video by url (../Media/Default/Video/video.mp4) and play it using html5 video player. But i get 404 error when trying to load it. I tried fix it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428639/cant-load-image-from-project-folder-in-orchard-module) but after that i get 500 error. I got this errors only on video files and only on server. On local machine everything working fine.

Comment: The 500 error probably means you have invalid web.config, a typo or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i fix it by adding MIME Type on IIS. There were no mime type for mp4. So i added .mp4 extension and video\mp4 mime type.