# How to Bind Image from table in Orchard cms

Tags: orchardcms

We have seen the all image required to register in web.config but how can I bind the dynamic images coming from database . Is there any approach to handle that problem ?

Comment: What do you mean with binding dynamic images from database? Where do you want to bind it to?

Comment: We have an image control in our view page.  To that image we need to bind the Employee's image which comes from database.

Comment: Sorry you need to explain more in your question. How is the image attached? Where do you want it to display?

Comment: To our mvc application we are able to bind the image.But the same thing in orchard it is saying as path not found. I heard that we need to register the images in web.config. we had taken the reference from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428639/cant-load-image-from-project-folder-in-orchard-module

Comment: Basically you need that web.config in every folder that contains static resources to tell IIS how to serve them but I don't think this applies to images that are stored elsewhere or are generated in code. How are your images stored in the database, where are the physical files and how do you retrieve them?

Comment: I have stored my database table in binary format .                                                                       like that : 0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010100000100010000FFE100A045786

Answer (score 0):

If you store your images in database, will be binding to byte array in the model, you must add an action to retrieve this images, then return it as "FileContentResult", as following:

```cs
public FileResult GetImage(int imageId) {
    ImageRecord imageRecord = _repo.Get(imageId);

    if (imageRecord != null) {
            return new FileContentResult(imageRecord.Image, imageRecord .MimeType);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.